# MassTransit - prevent a message going to the RMQ skipped queue, when a filter is used

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using MassTransit with RabbitMQ. Following the exmaple on the [official documentation page](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/custom.html) for custom middleware, I am trying to create a filter on the message consumption pipeline that will filter-out some messages based on a certain condition. My filter looks like this:

```
public class MyCustomFilter<T> : IFilter<T>
    where T : class, ConsumeContext
{
    public void Probe(ProbeContext context) { }

    public async Task Send(T context, IPipe<T> next)
    {
        if (/* certain condition */)
        {
            await next.Send(context);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the message is not passed down the pipeline (i.e. `await next.Send(context)` is not called), the message ends in the _skipped consumer RabbitMQ queue. Is there a way to prevent the message from going in that queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `skipped` (dead-letter) queue gets the message by the `DeadLetterFilter` invocation. Here is the code:

```
async Task IFilter<ReceiveContext>.Send(ReceiveContext context, IPipe<ReceiveContext> next)
{
    await next.Send(context).ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (context.IsDelivered || context.IsFaulted)
        return;

    context.LogSkipped();

    await _deadLetterPipe.Send(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

So, you could imagine that if the context has `IsDelivered` or `IsFaulted` set to `true`, your messages won't end up in the dead-letter queue.

If you throw in the filter, your messages end up in the poison (`error`) queue instead, so I guess that's not an option.

You can simulate your messages being delivered by doing something like this for filtered messages in your filter:

```
public Task Send(T context, IPipe<T> next)
    => condition
        ? next.Send(context)
        : context.NotifyConsumed(context as ConsumeContext<MyMessage>, TimeSpan.Zero, "Filtered");
```

Comment: Thank you, the code you provided led me to the right direction. I had to make a slight modification to my filter because I do not know the exact type of the message (i.e. `context as ConsumeContext<MyMessage>`) but I pass it as generic type argument to the filter class.
I have one question though - the docs say NotifyConsumed method is for internal usage. What are the chances this gets removed at some point?

Comment: Near zero, it's used throughout the stack and has been there for years. Alexey's approach is a good one. It's marked internal because people have a crazy habit of calling things they shouldn't.